# Expression doesn't match double quoted strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning about regular expressions and trying to make an expression that will match only those strings which are written in double quotes and for that my expression is : `"\S*"` and target string is `<aname="Name4"text="Super">`
but the expression is matching whole string after first double quoted string is found. I'm using this [website](http://regexr.com/) for testing an expression

Comment: And what do you expect to match? Try `"\S*?"`

Comment: If you are trying to parse XML in JavaScript you would not use a RegEx, there are built in methods to do it correctly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does `?` mean.

Comment: The `*?` is a lazy quantifier matching zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern, as few as possible.